# How do i change/swap colors in my image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

So i have the image:

```
I = [2 2 2 2 3 3 3;
     2 2 2 2 2 3 3;
     1 1 2 2 2 3 3;
     1 1 1 1 2 3 3;
     1 1 1 1 1 1 3;
     1 1 1 1 1 1 1;
     1 1 1 1 1 1 1];

figure, imshow(I, [], 'InitialMagnification','fit')     

RGBImage = label2rgb(I);
figure, imshow(RGBImage, 'InitialMagnification','fit');
```

In the `RGBImage` plot i have my pixels `I==3` as `yellow` and i want to keep them as they are; i have `I==1` as `blue`, but i want them to become `'red'` instead; and i also have `I==2` as `blueish-green?`, but i want them to have the color `'blue'` (as it is originally for `I==1`).

Could someone please kindly help me out with this? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `colormap` argument to `label2rgb`:

```
I = [2 2 2 2 3 3 3;
    2 2 2 2 2 3 3;
    1 1 2 2 2 3 3;
    1 1 1 1 2 3 3;
    1 1 1 1 1 1 3;
    1 1 1 1 1 1 1;
    1 1 1 1 1 1 1];
cm = [1,0,0;0,0,1;1,1,0];
RGBImage = label2rgb(I,cm);
figure, imshow(RGBImage, 'InitialMagnification','fit');
```

[image]